# How to count instances of a word in a list of words

Tags: c, search, sequential

I need to search for a word in a list of words in C, and count the occurrences of that word.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
{
    char *namePtr , *newnamePtr ; char  newname[1][8] ;
    int occurrence ;

    namePtr=&name[i];
    printf("enter the word you want to count : \n");
    scanf("%s",newname[1][8]);
    for(i=0; i< N ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(namePtr,newnamePtr)==0)
            occurrence++ ;
        else
            if(strcmp(namePtr,newnamePtr)!=0)
                printf("this word does not exist in  the list!");
    }
    printf("the occurrence  of this word is %d",occurrence) ;
}
```

How can I count the occurrences of a word in the list of words?

Comment: Start with proper layout; indentation is all over the place here.

Comment: the  program terminates at the middle of execution  it does not count the occurrence
.

Comment: Begin with a simple implementation i.e get the word to search, loop through the list of words comparing each with the word to be searched. Once you have achieved this you can think about using a binary tree or other relevant data structures to improve the performance. You seem to be on the right path at the moment.

Comment: @user3115387 what is the error you are seeing? Btw: The snippet you pasted above is it the main function?

Comment: start by defining the input and the output. If your list of word to search in is known before running the program it must be stored in some data structure. Same thing for the word you search. Is it user input, is it known ? It would probably be easier to define your program as a function and start by just calling it from main providing the necessary input (FYI: this is what is called a test, and the first step toward what is called TDD).

Comment: `char  newname[1][8] ;` --> `char  newname[8] ;` --> `scanf("%s", newname);`

Comment: `namePtr=&name[i];` into the loop.

Comment: `if(strcmp(namePtr,newnamePtr)!=0)` move to out of loop --> `if(occurrence==0)`

Comment: `occurrence ` need initialize to zero.

Comment: @meaning matters :  I started with the main program that reads an array of characters ,what is indentation ?

Comment: @Ifthikhan : no , this is the main , the main is an array of characters  that orders them in ascii and it works fine ,

Comment: @Ifthikhan : no , this isn't the main , the main is an array of characters (string)  that reads & orders them in ascii and it works fine , so in the search function , do I simply implement the list as a pointer to it ? aslo if i want to use a binary tree , does it need another loop ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : when I move it out of the loop it is syntax error,also it is returning the the loop counter and not the occurrence .

Comment: _when I move it out of the loop it is syntax error_ It was moved in if block? also Else block that is no longer content to delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want count substrings you can use this code:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char text[] = "foo bar foo bar foo";
    char word[] = "foo";
    char *p;
    int occurences = 0;

    for (p = text; (p = strstr(p, word)) != NULL; p += sizeof(word) - 1)
    {
        occurences++;
    }

    printf("Occurences of %s = %d\n", word, occurrences);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for a word within a sentence/list of words separated by delimiters, you could use the [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) and a loop to find all occurrences of that word.

A sample might be like this.

```
//strstr returns a pointer to first occurrence of the string found else NULL

do
{
   p=strstr(str1,str2);
   if(p) count++;

}while(p);
```

Also there a [several other algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10

char *name[N] = {
    "the", "name", "pointer", "the", "count",
    "word", "want", "to", "count", "exist"
};

int main(){
    char *namePtr , *newnamePtr ;
    char  newname[8];
    int i, occurrence = 0;

    printf("enter the word you want to count : \n");
    scanf("%s", newname);
    newnamePtr = newname;
    for(i=0; i< N ; i++){
        namePtr = name[i];
        if(strcmp(namePtr, newnamePtr)==0)//strcmp(name[i], newname)
            occurrence++;
    }
    if(occurrence==0)
        printf("this word does not exist in  the list!");
    else
        printf("the occurrence  of this word is %d", occurrence);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simplified version:

```
char newname[80];
int occurrence = 0;

printf("enter the word you want to count : \n");
scanf("%s", newname);
for (i = 0; i < N ; ++i)
{
    if( strcmp(name[i], newname) == 0 ) // access list directly
        ++occurrence;
    else // no need to check the inverse of the condition
        printf("this word does not exist in the list!");
}

printf("the occurrence  of this word is %d", occurrence) ;
```

**To count substrings (partial matches), replace:**

```
    if( strcmp(name[i], newname) == 0 ) // access list directly
```

with

```
    if( strstr(name[i], newname) != NULL ) // access list directly
```